# How to set MQTT connect as property in Jmeter and pass it to other thread to post messages on MQTT broker using Pub sampler

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, jmx

I want to set MQTT connect as a Jmeter property and use this connection in other thread which will post messages concurrently to MQTT broker. What I want to implement is

1. Set MQTT connect as Jmeter property
2. 1 thread which will use the connection to post messages to MQTT broker
3. MQTT disconnect

What I have done so far is using MQTT connect, Publish samplers and MQTT disconnect in same thread group. But when running multiple threads messages are getting failed to publish for other than thread-1.

Please let me know if there is any way to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that:

1. Moving the connection into another Thread Group
2. Trying to publish messages concurrently with multiple virtual users over a single connection

is a good idea because well-behaved JMeter test must represent real life usage of your application and each JMeter thread (virtual user) must represent an MQTT-enabled device which establishes its own connection to the broker. If the "messages are getting failed to publish" it indicates problem either with your test setup ([parameterization, correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), whatever) or with your MQTT broker so first of all I would check:

- whether all [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are having expected values
- [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- your MQTT broker log file
- your system under test log file

See [Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-the-mqtt-messaging-broker-for-iot-a-guide) article for more details.

---

If you're still looking for a way of passing the MQTT connection between thread groups you can do this using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following code:

1. To save the connection into a property:

   ```
   props.put('connection', vars.getObject('conn'))
   ```
2. To get the connection object from the property:

   ```
   vars.putObject('conn', props.get('connection'))
   ```

Comment: Messages are getting published for all samplers in Thread-1. But other than thread-1 in all the threads "messages are getting failed to publish" where all the threads are using the same MQTT connect sampler with same clientId and other connection details. Any idea if I am using same MQTT connect in all threads is it the expected behavior for the MQTT protocol i.e it will publish messages for only 1 thread and messages will get fail to publish for other than thread-1?